# Ruby modules for functions

Tags: ruby, methods, module

It is possible to add methods to a class using modules. E.g.,

```
class Test
  include Singleton
end
```

Is it possible to do the same with methods? E.g.,

```
class Test
  include Singleton

  def test
    include Instructions_to_add_to_the_method
    puts 'done'
  end
end
```

where:

```
module Instructions_to_add_to_the_method
  puts 'hi !'
end
```

When calling `Test.instance.test`, I want:

```
hi !
done
```

I do not wish to call another method, as it would give me issues with the scope of my variables.

Comment: No, that's not how ruby works. Modules are not macros. You could use `Module#prepend` or `Module#include` in conjunction with `super`, if that's what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to add methods to a class using modules. E.g.,
>
> ```
> class Test
>   include Singleton
> end
> ```

No. This does not "add methods to a class". `include` simply makes `Singleton` the superclass of `Test`. Nothing more. Nothing is being "added to a class". It's just inheritance.

> Is it possible to do the same with methods? E.g.,
>
> ```
> class Test
>   include Singleton
>
>   def test
>     include Instructions_to_add_to_the_method
>     puts 'done'
>   end
> end
> ```

There is no method `Test#include`, so this will simply `raise` a `NoMethodError`.

> When calling `Test.instance.test`, I want:
>
> ```
> hi !
> done
> ```

That's what inheritance is for:

```
class Test
  include Singleton

  def test
    super
    puts 'done'
  end
end

module Instructions_to_add_to_the_method
  def test
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class Test
  include Instructions_to_add_to_the_method
end

Test.instance.test
# hi
# done
```

Note that this way of using inheritance in Ruby is a little bit backward. If you really need something like this, you should use a language like Beta, where this is how inheritance works naturally.

A better solution would be something like the [Template Method Software Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?TemplateMethodPattern) which in Ruby can be something as simple as `yield`ing to a block:

```
class Test
  include Singleton

  def test
    yield
    puts 'done'
  end
end

Test.instance.test { puts 'hi' }
# hi
# done
```

or taking a `Proc` as an argument:

```
class Test
  include Singleton

  def test(prc)
    prc.()
    puts 'done'
  end
end

Test.instance.test(-> { puts 'hi' })
# hi
# done
```

or by calling a hook method:

```
class Test
  include Singleton

  def test
    extension_hook
    puts 'done'
  end

  def extension_hook; end
end

class HookedTest < Test
  def extension_hook
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

HookedTest.instance.test
# hi
# done
```

> I do not wish to call another method, as it would give me issues with the scope of my variables.

There are no variables in your code, so there can't possibly be any "issues" with them.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, it seems my understanding of Ruby class inheritance was a little bit off

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a terrible idea. Messing with your classes at run-time will make problems hard to debug (which version of that method was I calling there?) and your code hard to follow (oh, right, I can't call that method yet because it's not defined yet, I need to call this method first).

Given what you said at the end of your question about variable scoping, I'm almost certain that this won't solve the problem you actually have, and I'd suggest actually posting your actual problem.

That said, the question you asked can be answered by using the `included` and `extended` hooks which, unsurprisingly, fire when a module gets included and extended:

```ruby
module FooModule
  def self.included(base)
    puts 'FooModule included'
  end

  def self.extended(base)
    puts 'FooModule extended'
  end
  
  def new_method
    puts 'new method called'
  end
end

class Extender
  def test_extend
    self.extend FooModule
    puts 'done'
  end
end

class Includer
  def test_include
    self.class.include FooModule
    puts 'done'
  end
end

t1 = Extender.new
t2 = Extender.new
t1.test_extend # Prints out "FooModule extended" followed by "done"
t1.new_method # Prints out "new method called"
t2.new_method rescue puts 'error' # Prints out "error" - extend only modifies the instance that calls it

t1 = Includer.new
t2 = Includer.new
t1.test_include # Prints out "FooModule included" followed by "done"
t1.new_method # Prints out "new method called"
t2.new_method # Prints out "new method called" - all past and future instances of Includer have been modified
```